# Keeping Android Screen bright during Game

Tags: android

I have a game that uses the accelerometer to move a guy back and forth on the screen.  After a few seconds the screen goes dim.  Is there any way to keep it alive and bright during the game activity?

Answer (score 20):

With the [PowerManager API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html), you can acquire and release locks to:

- prevent your device to pause;
- prevent your device to dim;
- force brightness
- ...

Warning you must add one permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I try like that in oncreate on activity start

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 0):

This blog post covers the three ways of achieving this:

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/tut-keep-screen-onawake-3-possible-ways/

Basically, you either:

- tell android through your layout xml that you want to keep the screen alive
- tell android through a call to window manager to keep the screen on during oncreate
- use wakelocks to force the device to use full power at all time (and drain batteries)